# Docker: bash: /dev/null: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker, chroot, null, mknod

I use docker to unpack a linux chroot and then execute commands into it, but I get this inside the chroot.

```
echo ciao > /dev/null
bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

I thought that the null device must be corrupted so I tried something else:

```
rm -f /dev/null ; mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3; echo ciao > /dev/null 
bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

But it also did not work.

Doing `stat` on the main `/dev/null` and the one inside the chroot showed no difference at all.

I am writing this because it seems I was the first person in the writing about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

My chroot is being extracted on a tmpfs, for speed reasons, which I mount passing `--tmpfs /tmpfs:exec` to docker.

My mount was this:

```
tmpfs on /tmpfs type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)`
```

Turns out that, similarly to how I have to pass `exec` to override the default `noexec` that docker adds to tmpfs mounts, there is a `nodev` passed that I have to override.

So the parameter becomes this:

```
--tmpfs /tmpfs:exec,dev
```

The annoying part is that `mknod` does not fail or report any error. The device file is created but it won't work.